# How to install PrestaShop 1.7 RC0 from Composer

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've just cloned the `RC0` of PrestaShop 1.7.

I've run `composer install` but... what to do now?

I've tried to start the server with `app/console server:start` but, going to `127.0.0.1:8000` i receive this error:

> Front not yet implemented! Or to delete...

So, this seems not to be right way:

`app/console server:stop`

and try another way...

Go with the classic `localhost`:

> Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown
>   database 'dev-prestashop-1_7'

Ok, I've to create the database... Database `dev-prestashop-1_7` created... Try again...

> Table 'dev-prestashop-1_7.ps_shop_url' doesn't exist

Yes, it's normal that it doesn't exists: I've not yet created it!

But, now comes the question: how I configure PrestaShop?

**How can I start the installation procedure using the composer version of PrestaShop 1.7 RC0?**

Answer (score -2):

Once you have downloaded the zip of prestashop, you have to unzip it in a specified repo and give it the needed permissions. Then, you acces to this repo in a chosen browser.

For example (if you are under Linux system), let's say that your repo is called prestashop_1.7 and is put in /var/html/www, so you access to localhost/prestashop_1.7.

When accessing to this URL, un install unzipper will start and when finishing unzipping, it will lead you to the installation configuration.

You enter your configuration (you have to create the database manually) and that's it!